# How to submit my form with window.onload using ajax with data pulled from localstorage

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, onload

In my app I have an input form that uses a post route to find all information on an item based on a project ID. When you search for the project ID you can update and delete each field that is returned, but after you do either one of those actions the page, reloads, and you lose the project you were working on. I want to set the project ID into local storage when you first submit the page to find the information so that way when you edit or delete and the page refreshes it will make an AJAX call with the stored project ID in localstorage and then pull up the same project.

```
 $("#formData").on('submit', () => {

        localStorage.setItem('search', $('#search').val());

    });
```

Right now I'm getting a 500 internal server error. If anyone has an idea on how this can be done, I would greatly appreciate it!

```
window.onload = () => {
        const searchedId = localStorage.getItem('search')

        if (window.location.href.match('/find')) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/find',
                type: 'POST',
                data: searchedId,
            })
        }
    };
```

Comment: *I'm getting a 500 internal server error..* that is coming from server end. Check your terminal/consoles to know actual cause.

Comment: also, data needs to be an object, not a string, like `data: { searchterm: searchedId},`

Comment: Thanks  that fixed my error, However it still doesnt post on page load.

Comment: your code is testing for url and if it finds it, sending an ajax request to that same url

Answer (score 0):

Hello I tried to make it work with and make data as object in Ajax options try it out

- the solution is based on this answer:
  [window.onload vs $(document).ready()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready)

> document ready function (jquery) instead of window.load

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            const searchedId = localStorage.getItem('search')
    
            if (window.location.href.match('/find')) {
                $.ajax({
                    url:'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos',// working URL for dummy result
                    dataType: 'json', 
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: {searchterm: searchedId},
                    success: function(result,status, xhr){
                        console.log(status);
                    },
                    error: function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorMessage) {
                        console.log('error : '+errorMessage);
                   }
              });
            }
    });
```

I made this fiddle its work there is no internal error 500
https://jsfiddle.net/Abdelraoufferrah/q5dtxfw3/66/
sorry for the GET method its only because of the dummy data